# Is it correct to send Notifications from Controller to View?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, view, controller, notifications

I´m building an app which simulates an Inputstream of information from a sensor. When information are detected and parsed I want to send Notifications, that will be observed
by the different views which update themselves to a given timeintervall. 
Is its MVC compliant to use Notifications to get a connection from Model/Controller to the View?
I´m asking because I´m often reading about Views sending Notifications to the Controller when a User interacted with the UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view is supposed to be just a view and should not have to receive notifications to update itself. I am not saying I have not done this myself as it work having the view update itself. I would recommend that you design your application so that your view controllers receive the notifications and update the views appropriately. Use your views to display and interact with the user sending any interaction updates to your view controller and the view controller sending any display updates to the view.